# Environment variables for production on Gitlab

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, environment-variables, production

I need to set my website on gitlab pages .

Vue cli says me that I need to set a env variable

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/' + process.env.VUE_APP_CI_PROJECT_NAME + '/'
    : '/'
}
```

so I've made a .env file on root and I write it :

```
VUE_APP_CI_PROJECT_NAME = my_website
```

But when I console log it , it is undefined

my gitlab url is https://gitlab.com/my_name/company/my_website

so what am I need to write in my variable.

Comment: With my solution, you don't even need to set a condition: you can simply have different env variables (dev != production).

Answer (score 1):

When you push your app to production, you need to set the env variables on Gitlab and not in your `.env` which should be `.gitignore`'ed anyway.
The `.env` is essentially used for development purposes, and should not be committed.

To input some env variables on Gitlab, you can go to your `https://gitlab.com/your-group/your-project/-/settings/ci_cd` and find it there.
You can set `KEY` to `VUE_APP_CI_PROJECT_NAME` and `Value` to `my_website`.

Deploy again and it should work fine!

[image]